# Django | Static files served by nginx not used by Client

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django app, with the following settings for static files:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/static/'
```

I am running django using the follwoing gunicorn command:
`gunicorn evee.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000`.

I have configured nginx to serve the static files and ssl using the following conf:

```
  server {
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.home.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

    # path for static files
    root /opt;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://evee:8000;
    }
  }
```

Interesting part is that I am able to see the CSS in the client. For example, the request to `https://secapi.ril.com/static/admin/css/base.css` is successful and returns a 200 response. I can view all the static files at the URL mentioned, but django does not seem to use them. Have tried changing clients as well as private mode.

Am I doing something terribly wrong? This was working last time I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this. Had to edit the nginx.conf file to configure an upstream instead of redirecting it to http directly and removed a few headers that were being set. No clue how different it is or why this works. The entire setup is running in Docker Swarm.

```
#### SECAPI #####
  upstream app_server {
    # for a TCP configuration
    server evee:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.home.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

    # path for static files
    root /opt;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding static files path in your nginx config files as:

```
location /static/ {
    alias   /opt/static/;
}
```

Here mention complete path to your static folder. I guess in your case its `/opt/static/`

Comment: Does not work. Gives the same output. In this scenario as well I am able to see the css and js files, but the browser does not seems to use them.

Comment: @NerdSec Is `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes. It is present. I have also added this in the urls.py.
`urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('xyz/', include('xyz.urls')),
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: Is `DEFAULT=False` in settings.py file?

Comment: No, there is no such setting in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: And how are you loading static in templates file. It should be `{% load static %}`

Comment: Try defining static root as: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Comment: Thanks for the help Reema, but the issue wasn't with Django, but rather with Nginx.